# Create a map while preserving datatypes of the key and values from the multiple columns in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

Using PySpark 2.4.6

When creating a map column using the `create_map` or the `map_concat` for cols in Pyspark, the data types of the columns are by default converted into StringType(). Is there a way to preserve the datatypes when generating this new map column

For example:

```
Original dataframe (df)
df = df.withColumn("map_col", create_map(lit("col1"),col("col1"),
            lit("col2"), col("col2").cast(IntegerType()),
            lit("col3"), col("col3").cast(IntegerType())
            ))

col0 | col1 | col2 | col3| map_col
  s1 | Hello| 25   | 56  | [col1 -> Hello, col2 -> 25, col3 -> 56]
  s2 | Foo  | 33   | 62  | [col1 -> Foo, col2 -> 33, col3 -> 62]
  s3 | Bar  | 44   | 102 | [col1 -> Bar, col2 -> 44, col3 -> 102]
```

The above example creates a `df` with the following schema for col("map_col")

```
|-- map_col: map (nullable = false)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

and results in a JSON structure such as `["col1":"Hello","col2":"25","col3":"56"]` for the first row when grouped by `col0`

However, I am interested in generating the following JSON payload from this map column

`["col1":"Hello","col2":25,"col3":56]`

How can I achieve this?

So far I have tried creating separate map columns with `MapType(StringType(), IntegerType())` for one column and  `MapType(StringType(), StringType())` for another column and combine it using `map_concat` and `struct('col1', 'col2')` but none of them get me the payload I want.

I have also tried to use a `udf` such as the example below but am forced to use `MapType(StringType(), StringType())` to prevent the error from mismatch datatype.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import (
    to_json,
    col,
    collect_list,
    struct,
    create_map,
    lit,
    udf,
    map_concat,
    concat,
)

def create_dict(row):
    ''' Returns a dict json object for a dataframe row '''
    if row:
        return(json.loads(row))
    else:
        return None
udf_create_dict = udf(lambda row: create_dict(row), MapType(StringType(),StringType()))

 where 

df = df.select(struct(col("col1"), col("col2"), col("col3")).cast(schema).alias("inter1")\
.withColumn("inter2", to_json('inter1'))\
.withColumn("map_col", udf_create_dict(col("inter2"))).drop("inter2")

schema = StructType(
        [   
            StructField("col1", StringType()),
            StructField("col2", IntegerType()),
            StructField("col3", IntegerType()),
        ]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This question may be old, but I think my approach below will help if anyone is looking for solution to this issue.

We cannot have a `map` with different datatypes in pyspark; instead, we will have to use a `struct` in this case.

Below is an example:

```
#create a dataframe
rows = [['John', 543221,221.012],
        ['Adam', 6546,45.257],
        ]
  
columns = ['one', 'two','three']
df = spark.createDataFrame(rows, columns)

#create struct schema for the columns
struct_string = struct(col('one'),col('two').cast(IntegerType()),col('three')) 

#add the new column with struct schema
df = df.withColumn('test',struct_string)
df.display()
```